# rotate video opencv C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I have trying to rotate 90 degree the video from camera, I try to use `cvTranspose` and `cvFlip` but the results is:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x752bc41f in CameraStero.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0021faf8..
```

here my code.

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>

using namespace cv;



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 VideoCapture cap1;

 cap1.open(0);
 cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 0.55); 
 cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 800.0); 
 cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 800.0); 


 Mat img1, img2;

for(;;){


CvCapture* cap;
IplImage* frame;
cap = cvCreateCameraCapture( 0 );
cvGrabFrame(cap);
frame=cvRetrieveFrame(cap);




cvTranspose(frame, frame);
cvFlip(frame, frame, 1);


cvShowImage("Img1", frame);

    if(waitKey(1)=='q')
            break;
  }
 }
```

any suggestions to correct the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should leave the capture parameters being default as it may cause errors if the camera doesn't support the setting your set. So delete the following lines:

   ```
   cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 0.55); 
   cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 800.0); 
   cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 800.0);
   ```

   or if you do need to change width and height, you should make sure the width/height to be set should be smaller than default values. The following code will work too:

   ```
   cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 0.55); 
   cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320); 
   cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);
   ```
2. Like @SRF said, you are mixing up OpenCV C/C++ interface, so you either use

   ```
   cap = cvCreateCameraCapture( 0 );
   ```

   or

   ```
   cap1.open(0);
   ```

   , but not the both.
3. When you want to show the image your captured in one window, you should create the window first by:

   ```
   cv::namedWindow("Img1", 1);
   ```
4. Don't forget to `return 0;` in `int main()`. Although some compiler don't restrict this, you should do this as always.

---

After fixing all these, the code should look like this (works fine on my PC):

```
int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap1;

    cap1.open(0);
    cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 0.55); 
    cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320); 
    cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240); 
    cv::namedWindow("Img1", 1);

    Mat frame;
    for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap1 >> frame;

        transpose(frame, frame);
        flip(frame, frame, 1);

        imshow("Img1", frame);

        if(waitKey(1)=='q')
            break;
    }

    cap1.release();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is work but I need to set the frame width and height, I have  tried to use 'cap1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 800.0);' also for the height but the size did not change.

Comment: @Limavolt Updated the answer on how to set width/height correctly.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I am newbie in opencv

Comment: Just being clear, to rotate you just have to do `transpose(frame, frame); flip(frame, frame, 1);`. The "1" means rotate to the right, whereas "0" would mean rotate to the left 90 degrees. If you want to rotate more than once, just repeat the code again.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing OpenCV c++ and c interface. Here how it is done in OpenCV/C.

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CvCapture* cap = cvCreateCameraCapture( 0 );

    for(;;)
    {
       IplImage* frame=cvQueryFrame(cap);

       cvTranspose(frame, frame);
       cvFlip(frame, frame, 1);

       cvShowImage("Img1", frame);

       if(waitKey(30)=='q')
           break;
   }

   cvReleaseCapture(cap);
 }
```